# Email subscriptions system

Tags: emails

I'm looking for a way to have email subscribers database within Craft without using third-party solutions such as MailChimp.

I'm going to let users enter their emails to subscribe to site categories / channels and then send custom notifications with Postmaster plugin. Pre-defined subscriptions lists will not work for me.

I also don't have membership system.

So I wonder if there's any way to have subscribers database within Craft? Some plugin that people could use to submit their email and area of interest to subscribe and also to unsubscribe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds quite do-able. I will first admit I don't know how postmaster works at all, so I could be way off in my suggestion. Regardless, you're looking at two plugins working together; a contact form & postmaster.

I would start with the [contact form plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm), but modify it a bit so that it captures the users's information. Depending on your needs, I would either have a checkbox so the user could select which section they wanted notifications for, or have a hidden field that is pre-populated with the current section - then just pass that through.

If you want to have a visual representation of these records, you'll either want to look at creating entries for them, or just capture them within the plugin. I have an example of both to help get you rolling. DM me on the slack channel and I can send you my examples.

Here is where I'm not sure how to help. Once you have the information, somehow you'll need to tell postmaster where those records are, loop through and send an email. I'm guessing at this point creating entires that represent subscribers would be easier for postmaster to understand?

Comment: Hi @Damon - thanks for the responce. For the Postmaster notification, I will obviously have some custom code to pull only those recipients that I need for each case. May question is rather regarding subscription/unsuscription system. Modyfying one of exsiting form plugins is one of the approaches that I consider, however I was hoping to find some ready-to-use solution.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be too tough. Just start with the contact form plugin that the guys @ P&T have set up. Then at the part where it sends the email is where you can modify the plugin to either just capture/store the email addresses or create entries.

Comment: While this is not exact solution I've been looking for, I'm acceptng this answer as this is the approach I've finally taken. Thank you!